# Django translation plural not working

Tags: django, translation, osqa

I am pretty new to Django. I have the following code in the template:

```
 {% blocktrans count answers.paginator.count as
 counter %}One Answer:{% plural %}{{counter}} Answers:{% endblocktrans %}
```

And the following line in the django PO (generated)

```
#: forum/skins/default/templates/question.html:149
#, python-format
msgid "One Answer:"
msgid_plural "%(counter)s Answers:"
msgstr[0] "Один ответ:"
msgstr[1] "%(counter)s ответа/-ов:"
```

Now the singular translation is working, but the plural somehow is not... Any idea what is missing?

Not working means that the output is;

"Один ответ"  if counter is 1

"5 Answers" in case the counter is 5

So the counter is working.

Thanks,
Pleun

Comment: Try changing `answers.paginator.count as
 counter` to `counter=answers.paginator.count` (as provided in docs)

Comment: `count foo as bar` is old usage, try `bar=foo` as ilvar said, if you're using relative new version of Django (1.3+). Also, what does "not working" exactly mean?

Comment: I updated "not working" in the question. @ilvar I installed a trunk version of Osqsa "as is" I have not done anything with the sources/templates themselves so I would like to keep it that way. In all other cases translation is doing fine but I will try it anyway

Comment: In `settings_local` template OSQA has `DJANGO_VERSION = '1.1'`, so it can be easily non-fully-compatible with modern Django. Try using 1.3, maybe.